# I want to generate a regular array

Tags: php, math

I want to generate a regular array.Using 1 to n.Here's an example of a 6 dimensional array

01  02  04  07  11 16
03  05  08  12 17 22
06  09  13 18 23 27
10 14 19 24 28 31
15 20 25 29 32 34
21 26 30 33 35 36

Here is my code.
But the number of generated arrays is more than I wanted

```
$size = 6;
for ( $i = 0; $i < $size * 2 - 1 ; $i++ )
{
    for ( $j = 0 , $i_temp = $i ; $j <= $i ; $j++ , $i_temp-- )
    {
        if( $i < $size )
        {
            if( $i == 0 && $j == 0 )
            {
                $arr[ $j ][ $i_temp ] = 1;
            } 
            else 
            {
                if( $j == 0 )
                {
                    $arr[ $j ][ $i_temp ] = $arr[ $i_temp - 1 ][ $j ] +1;
                }
                else
                {
                    $arr[ $j ][ $i_temp ] = $arr[ $j - 1 ][ $i_temp + 1 ] + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ( $i_temp < $size - 1  )
            {
                $arr[ $j ][ $i_temp ] = $arr[ $j - 1 ][ $i_temp + 1 ] + 1;
            }
            if ( $i_temp == $size - 1 )
            {
                $arr[ $j ][ $i_temp ] = $arr[ $i_temp ][ $j - 1 ] + 1;
            }
        }

    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

Here is result.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 7
            [4] => 11
            [5] => 16
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 8
            [3] => 12
            [4] => 17
            [5] => 22
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 9
            [2] => 13
            [3] => 18
            [4] => 23
            [5] => 27
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 14
            [2] => 19
            [3] => 24
            [4] => 28
            [5] => 31
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 25
            [3] => 29
            [4] => 32
            [5] => 34
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21
            [1] => 26
            [2] => 30
            [3] => 33
            [4] => 35
            [5] => 36
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 27
            [1] => 31
            [2] => 34
            [3] => 36
            [4] => 37
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 32
            [1] => 35
            [2] => 37
            [3] => 38
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 36
            [1] => 38
            [2] => 39
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 39
            [1] => 40
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 41
        )

)
```

I can't find the mistake.
Can someone help me?

Comment: I'm going to generate each of these columns diagonally.For example,a[0][3],a[1][2],a[2][1],a[3][0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if ( $i < $size )
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

to

```
if( $i < $size )
{
    ...
}
else if ( $j < $size )
{
    ...
}
```

as you don't want for $j to exceed the size of your array. The other possibility is to take care of this in your inner loop:

```
for ( $j = 0 , $i_temp = $i ; $j <= min( $i , $size - 1 ) ; $j++ , $i_temp-- )
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why should the OP change that? And what should `elsif` do?

Comment: The first method works, but the second method doesn't.

Comment: In your mind, I changed the inner loop like this:`for ( $j = 0 , $i_temp = $i ; $j <= $i && $j < $size  ; $j++ , $i_temp-- )`.That's ok

Comment: Yeah of course `<=` vs. `<` ... Corrected the answer.